# Accidentally deactivated lalt

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I was messing around with my compose key, and although I was finally successful, in the process I have somehow unbound my `lalt` key.  Any shortcuts involving the `lalt` key no longer works (most annoyingly, alt+tab).  Is there a way to reset this?

I am on xubuntu 16.04

[I should also mention that I have installed CompizConfig and have it set properly, but Alt+Tab still does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExlAK.png)

I also tried resetting the shortcut defaults in Settings > Keyboard but it still doesn't work.  I think the left left alt key just isn't sending any information or something